# How to resolve SELECT PERMISSION DENIED error in power BI dataflow

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a dataflow that is being refreshed weekly and was last refreshed successfully few days ago. Today I added another table to the dataflow and tried to refresh it - it is getting failed due to a pre-existing table in the dataflow having select permission denied error.

The old table uses a reference to b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws.t04056 - which is working fine when I try to query from it in synapse. I am not sure why the issue is occurring.

**The error message from power query:**

*Microsoft SQL: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056', database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod', schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'.DetailsReason = DataSource.Error
DataSourceKind = SQL
DataSourcePath = tcp-azu0011-ase-sql-b2bdp-prod.database.windows.net;tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod
Message = The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056', database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod', schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'.
ErrorCode = -2146232060
Number = 229*

## **Error log from the refresh fail:**

Error: Encountered user gateway exception: 'Microsoft SQL: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode]=-2147467259 [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage]=Microsoft SQL: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult]=-2147467259 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Class]=14 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind]=SQL [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath]=tcp-azu0011-ase-sql-b2bdp-prod.database.windows.net;tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.ErrorCode]=-2146232060 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Message]=The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Number]=229 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason]=DataSource.Error [InnerType]=MashupValueException Microsoft SQL: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [GatewayPipelineErrorCode]=DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError [ErrorShortName]=GatewayClientErrorResponseException[GatewayId=240974]/MashupDataAccessValueException[ErrorCode=-2147467259 HResult=-2147467259]/Wrapped(MashupValueException)[ErrorCode=-2147467259 HResult=-2147467259] [ExceptionErrorShortName]=GatewayClientErrorResponseException[GatewayId=240974]'. RootActivityId = f100f2d6-3d26-4f2e-8fda-c51ab7ada0e3.Param1 = Microsoft SQL: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode]=-2147467259 [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage]=Microsoft SQL: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult]=-2147467259 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Class]=14 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind]=SQL [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath]=tcp-azu0011-ase-sql-b2bdp-prod.database.windows.net;tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.ErrorCode]=-2146232060 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Message]=The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Number]=229 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason]=DataSource.Error [InnerType]=MashupValueException Microsoft SQL: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 't04056'  database 'tcp-azu0011-ase-sdw-b2bdp-prod'  schema 'b2b_stg_flexcab_active_conf_vws'. [GatewayPipelineErrorCode]=DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError [ErrorShortName]=GatewayClientErrorResponseException[GatewayId=240974]/MashupDataAccessValueException[ErrorCode=-2147467259 HResult=-2147467259]/Wrapped(MashupValueException)[ErrorCode=-2147467259 HResult=-2147467259] [ExceptionErrorShortName]=GatewayClientErrorResponseException[GatewayId=240974] Request ID: e760b635-a5c4-0bd6-078d-99322446acca.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I

Comment: Maybe this powerBI thing isn't ran by your user and the user that runs it doesn't have select permissions